# How to plot multiple facet_col in pyhthon using plotly.express

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization

I have this plotly express scatter plot of imdb_rating vs runtime having facet columns of genre_1[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdEbz.png)

But instead of all the genres I just want the plot to include three genres (namely 'Action,Drama and Biography),.What tweaks should I make to my code to achieve the desired output(shown in image)[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdABK.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this page as a reference, I wrote some code that can produce the output you expect. To create multiple graphs with category variables, use `facet_col`.

**Important:** Posting code or data as images is not recommended. It is not recommended to post code or data in images, because it is too much work for the respondents and they will be reluctant to answer. As a result, you will not get a quick answer.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20210226)
genre_1 = random.choices(['Action','Drama','Biography'], k=100)
rating = [random.uniform(7.0, 9.0) for i in range(100)]
runtime = [random.randint(85, 180) for n in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'genre_1':genre_1, 'rating':rating,'runtime':runtime})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(df, x="runtime", y="rating", color="genre_1", facet_col="genre_1",
       category_orders={"genre_1": ["Action", "Drama", "Biography"]})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!